# Can you embed the standard activity history "send an email" page into a page layout?

Tags: singleemailmessage, send-email, activityhistory

[image: Standard Activity History > Send an Email button]

[image: Standard Activity History > Send an Email page]

It takes too much time (UX) to get to the Standard Send an Email page.  Instead of hovering the mouse over "Activity History" and clicking "Send an Email" to get to the "Send an Email" rich text editor page, can I just embed it into a Page Detail layout without having to write any visualforce or html? I have considered adapting this solution (http://anuragsfdc.blogspot.com/2015/02/send-email-using-apex-and-vf-page-by.html) to work as an embedded visualforce page on standard detail pages but I think I am overthinking this.

Any clues / hints / ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a hack not a solution. I'm saying 'hack' because there is no guarantee that Salesforce will let keep it working as it is in future. But for now you can utilize it. There are some steps that you have to follow and you'll have your very own email sending button on your object.

1. Create a custom button.
2. Add the custom button on your page layout.
3. Edit the custom button and type in a URL with your custom parameters.

**Create a custom button**
You can create custom button by going under

> setup->Create->Objects

and edit your object. Scroll down to the following section and press **New Button or Link** button. Give *label, name and description* to your button and **Save**.

[image]

**Add custom button on Page Layout**
To add custom button on your page layout scroll to the page layouts section and **Edit** the page layout on which you want to add this button.

[image]

Then just drag & drop the button on the Custom buttons section and save the layout.

[image]

**Edit the custom button** Now this time you have to scroll to the Buttons, Links, and Actions section and edit your custom button.

[image]

Once in this section here are the following things you need to focus on.
 1. URL of Email Author
 2. Parameters list

**URL of Email Author** Following is the base URL of email author you need to point on.

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor
```

If you simply put this piece of URL in front of your org's base address like this you'll get a pretty email author opened and all it is waiting is your input and the time you'll hit the **Send** button.

[image]

Apparently by your question this is all you need. But if you need to pre fill some of the information and also have an email template that you want to pull your email content from then you need to consider the following parameters list and add them into the mix. You can get the guidance from the attached screenshot of Edit button. And for your reference I'll add the complete URL at the bottom of this answer which is actually customized according to my needs and for my org.

**Parameters list** Below is the map of parameter name to parameter value.

```
p2_lkid                 To (can be Contact or Lead Id)
p3_lkid                 *Related To (usually the parent record Id)
p4                      CC
p5                      BCC
p6                      Subject
p23                     Email Body
p24                     Additional To
Template_Id             Salesforce email template Id
retURL                  *Redirection page when cancel button is clicked
```

> Complete URL for your reference

```
/_ui/core/email/author/EmailAuthor?
retURL=/{!Candidate__c.Id}&
p3_lkid={!Candidate__c.Id}&
rtype=003&
p2_lkid={!Candidate__c.candidateEmail__c}&
template_id=00X90000001BB1XEAW&
p24={!Candidate__c.candidateEmail__c}
```

I hope it will help you and for any further questions you're welcome to ask under comments. Thanks.